# Dlib cuda face detection .dat model crash on GTX 1650 while being good on many other gpu devices

Tags: python, nvidia, dlib, nvidia-docker

I got the same Dockerfile and the same code as below but the result different

One gives correct printouts while another crashes without any message!!

#### code

```py
import dlib
import cv2
print(dlib.__version__)  # 19.17.99, the same

cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")    

rects = cnn_face_detector(img, 1)  # one crashes every time on this line
print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(rects))) 

for i, d in enumerate(rects):
    face = d.rect
    print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {} Confidence: {}".format(i, face.left(), face.top(), face.right(), d.rect.bottom(), d.confidence))

    cv2.rectangle(img, (face.left(),face.top()), (face.right(),face.bottom()), (0,0,255),2)
```

#### command to run

`nvidia-docker run -it --rm -w="/usr/src/app" -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app myDocEnv test.py`

#### correct ouput

```
19.17.99
Number of faces detected: 1
Detection 0: Left: 245 Top: 100 Right: 415 Bottom: 269 Confidence: 1.079284906387329
```

#### incorrect output

```
19.17.99
```

#### the only difference

The only difference between them is the GPU hardware device

The one who crashes use **GeForce GTX 1650**
while it runs without trouble on **P620**、**1050Ti**

Comment: `crashes without any message` means you didn't add any error handling or logging code to your script, and the console output isn't logged anywhere. Perhaps you forgot some drivers? Or the input image isn't where you expect it to be? There are 3 statements that could throw in your script

Comment: thanks for the response!

I'm pretty sure img is not None
and I get nothing even with try-catch

print(img.shape')
try:
    print("happend here!")
`'    rects = cnn_face_detector(img, 1)  # one crashes every time on this line`

`'    print("nothing printed out")`

`'    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(rects)))`

`except Exception as e:`

`'    print(e)`

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda/nccl/lib && \
         ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnccl.so.2 /usr/local/cuda/nccl/lib/ &&\
         ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         libcublas10 \
         libcublas-dev
RUN apt install -y libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler

RUN export CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
```

adding these few things fixed my problem